# TSQL Query help calculating time difference between records where a bit flag changes from 0 to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff, date-arithmetic

I need some help with a TSQL query. I am needing to calculate total time where the bit flag in my table below = '1'. My blocker here is there are millions of potential records and I am needing to base this off of one 'LogDate' column. So I assume I need to create a "Time Start" for when the bit flag changes from 0 to 1 and a "Time End" when it goes back from 1 to 0 then iterate through and do a datediff.

My challenge with only having basic SQL knowledge, this is out of my wheelhouse. Any magic that can be shared?

Need to group these starts/ends and do the arithmetic on total hh:mm:ss

Example data:

```
LogDate             StateBit
12/25/17 6:41:30    0
12/25/17 6:42:45    1 <-- Start time 
12/25/17 6:44:25    1
12/25/17 6:44:40    1
12/25/17 6:44:55    1
12/25/17 6:56:11    1
12/25/17 7:00:19    1
12/25/17 7:00:34    1
12/25/17 7:02:04    1
12/25/17 7:02:43    1
12/25/17 7:02:58    1 <-- End time 
12/25/17 7:03:15    0
```

Comment: Please don't use image to post sample data as it'll be hard for the anyone to  use it.

Comment: I *think* this is probably a gaps and islands question (you may want to research this first OP). Would be great to get the sample data in a consumable format as well as expected output if you struggle; just make sure you post what you've tried as well.

Comment: ok cool, reading up on gaps and islands now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the groups as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_bit = bit then 0 else 1 end) over (order by dt) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(bit) over (order by dt) as prev_bit
      from t
     ) t;
```

Then you can accumulate the periods for each group:

```
select min(dt), max(dt), bit
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_bit = bit then 0 else 1 end) over (order by dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(bit) over (order by dt) as prev_bit
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, bit;
```

I think you can use this information to get the total spans that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use this way

```
-- You need to have changed states rows and dates of before states in one row (the best choice is first rows of changed states
;with MakeLag as (select *,Lag(StateBit)over(order by id) ld,Lag(LogDate)over(order by LogDate)lDt  from #t )

--Next Step is to calculate seconds between this Two dates
,CalcSeconds as(select *,datediff(second,lDt,LogDate) as Dif from MakeLag where ld<>StateBit)

--And for finish you need to change these datediffs to "dd hh:mm:ss"
select *, CAST(FLOOR(Dif / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, Dif, '19000101'), 8) as FinDiff from CalcSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is quite simple, might have misunderstood your need, but if you filter according to a stateBit, just subtract the min and max.

```
select max(logdate) - min (logdate) from tbl where StateBit = 1;
```